# Sudden networking problems in Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Tags: networking, ubuntu-18.04

This morning the networking in my Ubuntu 18.04 Server Edition machine is not working anymore :

```
marco@pc01:$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network DISABLED
      description: Ethernet interface
      product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express 
        Gigabit Ethernet Controller
  *-network DISABLED
      description: Wireles interface
      product: AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name : docker0
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
```

`sudo nano /etc/nework/interfaces` :

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.7
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.1 
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    post-up iptables-restore <  
      /etc/iptables.up.rules
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.5 8.8.8.8

marco@pc01:$ sudo service network-manager restart
 Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service 
  not found
```

Even with `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`:

```
marco@pc01:$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
[ok] Restarting networking (via systemctl):
 networking.service

marco@pc01:$ ping 192.168.1.4
 connect: Network is unreachable


marco@pc01:$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKOWN group
       default qlen 1000
   inet 27.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 ::1/128 scope host
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group 
       default qlen 1000
     link/ether 78:24:af:43:ef:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group 
       default qlen 1000
     link/ether c0:4a:00:09:0e:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
4: b3-4f9fe03b1a66: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc 
       noqueue state DOWN group default
     link/ether 02:42:64:29:65:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
     inet 172.22.0.1/16 brd 172.22.255.255 scope global br-4f9fe03b1a66
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue 
      state DOWN group default
    link/Ether 02:42:01:ea:90:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scoper global docker0
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


marco@pc01:$ ifconfig eth0 up eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: 
  eth0: ERROR while getting interface flgs: No such device
  eth0: Host name lookup failure

marco@pc01:$ ifconfig
br-4f9feo3b1a66: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 192.22.0.1 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 172.22.255.255
    ether 02:42:4d:c4:bd:62 txqueuelen 0 (Ethernet) 
    RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0B)
    RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
    TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<,UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtue 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 172.17.255.255
    ether 02:42:24:b9:3b:59 txqueuelen 0 (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
    TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

l0: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1 prefoxlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 258 bytes 32343 (32.3 KB) 
    RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
    TX packets 258 bytes 32343 (32.3 KB)  
    TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0



/etc/network/interfaces :

  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback
```

4° Update:

```
  marco@pc01:$ uname -r
  4.15.0-55-generic

  marco@pc01:$ ls -al /etc/netplan
  total 20
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 25 18:37
  drwxr-xr-x 128 root root 12288 Jul 25 12:51
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 616 Jul 25 18:37 30-cloun-init.yaml

   etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml    :

     network:
         renderer: NetworkManager/ networkd
         ethernets:
           enp3s0:
               addresses: [192.168.1.7/24]
               gateway4: 192.168.1.1
               nameservers:
                   addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
               dhcp4: no
         version: 2

 marco@pc01:$ sudo netplan apply
 sudo: netplan: command not found
```

For `sudo llshw -c network` : see above

What have I to do in order to make the network available again?
Looking forward to your kind help
Marco

Answer (score 0):

It says "eth0: ERROR while getting interface flgs: No such device" right there. Perhaps a driver problem or deactivated/unusable hardware. Check system logs, especially the kernel. The other errors would be secondary or, in some cases, you may have mistyped commands (I am not familiar with Ubuntu).

(Linux has become soo complicated, also with networking...)